# My favourite animal is a dog, the dog or dog

Tags: sentence, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I consider myself a pretty advanced English teacher and user. Nonetheless, I've recently found myself in a pretty difficult spot trying to explain which of the following sentences is correct:

> My favourite animal is a dog
>
> My favourite animal is the dog
>
> My favourite animal is dog

My instinct tells me ***the dog*** is the correct one, but I've found so many instances on the internet where native speakers say **My favourite animal is dog** that makes me wonder if that sentence is also correct.

Additionally, I know that a sentence like **My favourite food is pizza** sounds pretty right to me, making the whole thing so complicated that I cannot figure out any rule that governs using articles in the above sentences.

Comment: My favourite animal is the dog , means the category of animal you prefer (correct one here)
My favourite animal is a dog, means a particular dog (the one you've at home, for example)
My favourite animal is dog, would be okay if you were eating dog meat

Comment: An English teacher would not write english and might consider putting a conjunction between teacher and user.

Comment: @P.Obertelli I think it's the other way around!

Comment: @P.Obertelli- Good comment: smart, insightful and funny! You should clean it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I'm at work I didn't have time to support my answer with all the bell and whisttles required on the site.

Comment: 'Dog' is entirely wrong. It should be 'cat'.

Comment: @AnthonyBlake- no, he’s got it the right way ’round.

Comment: That's odd... when I google "my favorite animal is dog," I mostly find it used by non-native speakers, and in grammatical discussions where native speakers say it sounds odd.

Comment: @Rathony what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

> My favourite animal is the dog

As P. Obertelli mentioned in comments, the one with the **definite article** is correct. The definite article is used before a singular noun to represent the whole class.

> When a singular noun is meant to represent **a whole class** to which it belongs, it is used with the definite article *the*.
>
> - **The cow** is a useful animal. (Here the singular noun *cow* represents a whole class.)
> - **The rose** is the sweetest of all flowers.
> - **The spider** has eight legs.

([englishgrammar.org](http://www.englishgrammar.org/definite-article/))

You can google all kinds of usage, but in my opinion that is no excuse for educated English speakers to blindly accept *everything* you can find without a good reason or sound judgement. So I would say dropping the article is wrong here, even though the context would probably make it clear what you mean.

Others might disagree, but I'm on the side of [Bryan A. Garner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_A._Garner) here, who calls himself a descriptive prescriptivist.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: @Rathony Thank you, but I do hope someone more knowledgeable about grammar weighs in on this.